# Pass certificate from Ngnix Server to other Nginx Server for client authentication

Tags: linux, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have one Ngnix Server [Frond End say xx.xx] and other Ngnix server [Other Backend Server say yy.yy]

if using curl command i am passing client cetificate and key on yy.yy server i am getting success from the backend server

Problem :
if using curl command i am passing client cetificate and key on xx.xx server i am getting error

## 400 Bad Request

No required SSL certificate was sent

So in my case xx.xx is not passing certificate to yy.yy server

Please help me

For yy.yy server

```
server {
    listen       443;

    server_name  yy.yy
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/yyyycert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/yy.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ca-chain-scb.cert.pem;   
    ssl_verify_client on;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-User     $remote_user;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}

server {
    listen       443;

    server_name  xx.xx
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/xxxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/xx.key;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    location ~ ^/SCB/(.*)$  {
        proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
        rewrite /SCB(.*) $1  break;
        proxy_pass https://yy.yy:443;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your nginx configs

Comment: For xx.xx server

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  xx.xx;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/xx.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/xx.key;

  location ~ ^/SCB/(.*)$  {
       proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
       rewrite /SCB(.*) $1  break;
       proxy_pass https://yy.yy:443;
}
}

Comment: Post that in question and not in comments. And post both side configs

Comment: For yy.yy server

server {
    listen       443;

    server_name  yy.yy
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/yyyycert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/yy.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ca-chain-scb.cert.pem;   
    ssl_verify_client on;
   location / {
       proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-User     $remote_user;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

}

Comment: Same has been done Tarun

Answer (score 2):

The backend server is generating the 400 error because it never receives any client certificates. All incoming SSL sessions are being terminated at the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy then creates a new session to connect to the backend. Normally, the proxy doesn't send a client certificate when attempting to connect, hence your error.

If you want to enforce client certificate authentication on the backend with the reverse proxy in place, you could use the directives [`proxy_ssl_certificate`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_certificate), `proxy_ssl_certificate_key`, and [`proxy_ssl_verify`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify) on the reverse proxy server. These would make the proxy authenticate to the backend with it's own client certificate. This is not the same as the backed receiving and validating the original client certificates, as they are not passed in the connection to the backend.

If you need to pass the original client certificate information to the backend, you can do so by sending the variable [`$ssl_client_cert`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_cert) in a request header when connecting to the backend. [This page](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/client-certificate-x509-authentication-behind-reverse-proxy/start) has an example using various certificate properties. Note that this is still not the same as the backend validating the original client certificate, but can be used to similar effect, assuming the backend trusts the reverse proxy, and vice-versa.

Currently it is not possible for the backend server to validate the original client certificate while behind a reverse proxy. This is not a limitation of Nginx (or Apache), but is due to how SSL works when using client certificate authentication.